# set Textview on imageview using android:layout_centerInParent="true" not working

Tags: android

I am trying to have set a text view over a image view , in the example they mentioned I should use to work

```
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

but it is not working

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jpi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Insert" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jpi"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="hiiiiiii"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Create photo"
        android:onClick="SignUp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to set a textview on imageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

only works when the parent layout is a RelativeLayout, not a LinearLayout.

If you want to center the image in the view, either change the root view to a RelativeLayout, or use a FrameLayout as root layout and use layout_gravity="center" for the ImageView.

Possible solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jpi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:hint="Insert"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="hiiiiiii" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="SignUp"
        android:text="Create photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```